QGIS points move relative to the OSM basemap when zoomed IN or OUT while using OpenLayers
I am trying to create a web map with the locations of stores; however, whenever I attempt to zoom in or out, the positions change relative to the OSM base map (XYZ) I have.
I am using EPSG:32644 and have the "match project CRS" option checked. I am using OpenLayers, and this issue does not occur in Leaflet. However, the base map is not visible at all for this CRS in Leaflet.
What can I do?


Can you edit the question by attaching your QGIS project somewhere with the data and linking it here?

Maybe a related topic: https://github.com/andreaordonselli/qgis2o.gis/issues/16

As I have just learned, the topics are not related after all.

Does the same problem occur with other base layers?
